Redefining special commands in ConTeXt
i want to use itemgroup for typesetting side by side poems,
this MWE works well:
\defineitemgroup[myPoem]
\starttext
\startitemgroup[myPoem][horizontal,two]
\startitem first sentence \stopitem\startitem second sentence \stopitem
\startitem third sentence \stopitem\startitem fourth sentence \stopitem
\stopitemgroup
\stoptext

but this MWE doesn't work:
\defineitemgroup[myPoem]

\def\PoemStart{\startitemgroup[myPoem][horizontal,two] \startitem}
\def\NextStanza{\stopitem \startitem}
\def\PoemStop{\stopitem \stopitemgroup}

\starttext
\PoemStart
first sentence \NextStanza second sentence \NextStanza
third sentence \NextStanza fourth sentence
\PoemStop
\stoptext

what is the problem with definition? it seems that it is related to the way TeX processes the content and the grouping within macros but i also cannot even define a command for equivalent of commands such as just \NC.
this is also important for defining equivalent of such commands for another language.
what command should i use for such definitions? should i use \let or \expanded or any other commands with definition?


what is the problem with definition? it seems that it is related to the way TeX processes the content and the grouping within macros

The issue is that \startitem is a so-called delimited macro; that is, it scans for its arguments until it sees exactly \stopitem. The only way to wrap these types of commands it to make sure that both the command and its delimiter are contained inside of the macro body. A short example document:
\def\TestStart{\starttest}
\def\NextTest{\stoptest\starttest}
\def\TestStop{\stoptest}

\startTEXpage[offset=1ex]
    %%% Variant 1: Works
    \def\starttest{\bold\bgroup}
    \def\stoptest{\egroup\unskip,\ }

    \starttest One \stoptest
    \starttest Two \stoptest

    %%% Variant 2: Works
    \TestStart
        Three \NextTest Four
    \TestStop

    %%% Variant 3: Works
    \def\starttest#1\stoptest{\bold{#1\unskip},\ }

    \starttest Five \stoptest
    \starttest Six \stoptest

    %%% Variant 4: Doesn't work
    % \TestStart
    %     Seven \NextTest Eight
    % \TestStop

    %%% Variant 5: Works
    \def\TestStart#1\NextTest#2\TestStop{%
        \starttest#1\stoptest
        \starttest#2\stoptest
    }

    \TestStart
        Nine \NextTest Ten
    \TestStop
\stopTEXpage


For more details on delimited arguments, see §11.5.1 of “TeX by Topic” or §9 of “TeX in a Nutshell”.

commands such as just \NC […] should i use \let

For the specific case of \NC, you can use \let:
\def\newNCone{\NC}
\let\newNCtwo=\NC

\startTEXpage[offset=1ex]
    \startTABLE
        %%% Variant 1: Doesn't work
        % \newNCone One \newNCone Two \newNCone\NR

        %%% Variant 2: Works
        \newNCtwo Three \newNCtwo Four \newNCtwo\NR
    \stopTABLE
\stopTEXpage



this is also important for defining equivalent of such commands for another language.

ConTeXt already supports commands in multiple languages:
% interface=fr

\définirgroupedéléments[MaPoème]

\débutTEXpage[decalage=1ex]
    \débutMaPoème[horizontal, deux]
        \débutélément premier phrase \finélément
        \débutélément deuxième phrase \finélément
        \débutélément troisième phrase \finélément
        \débutélément quatrième phrase \finélément
    \finMaPoème
\finTEXpage


See the “Language” page on the ConTeXt Wiki for a full list of supported languages. If you want to use a language not on there, you can email a list of translations to the ConTeXt mailing list.

i want to use itemgroup for typesetting side by side poems, […] what command should i use for such definitions?

If you need to stick strictly to the interface given in the question, you can (ab)use buffers for this:
% Define the commands that you want to be eventually ran in the buffer
\defineitemgroup[myPoem]

\def\doPoemStart{\startitemgroup[myPoem][horizontal,two]\startitem}
\def\doPoemStop{\stopitem \stopitemgroup}
\def\doNextStanza{\stopitem \startitem}

% Define the buffer processor
\define\PoemStart{\grabbufferdata[myPoem][PoemStart][PoemStop]}
\let\NextStanza=\relax

\startluacode
    local doPoemStart = tokens.getters.macro("doPoemStart")
    local doPoemStop = tokens.getters.macro("doPoemStop")
    local doNextStanza = tokens.getters.macro("doNextStanza")

    interfaces.implement {
        name = "PoemStop",
        public = true,
        actions = function()
            local buffer = buffers.getcontent("myPoem")

            buffer = buffer:gsub("\\NextStanza", doNextStanza)
            buffer = doPoemStart .. buffer .. doPoemStop

            context(buffer)
        end
    }
\stopluacode

% Demonstration
\startTEXpage[offset=1em]
    \PoemStart
        first sentence \NextStanza second sentence \NextStanza
        third sentence \NextStanza fourth sentence
    \PoemStop
\stopTEXpage


